# Jquery multiple select with same text not same val

Tags: jquery, select

Hello i have to make 3 select input with the same "option text" but value is different.
i want to make disabled item on other select when is selected on one of this
i have try this but not work :
     [jsfiddle Test](http://jsfiddle.net/10tribu/8hzLo7n2/1/)

inspired by this: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xL8p478y/2/)

```
$(".activ select").on('focus', function ()
        {
    previous = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    }).change(function() {      
    var previoues_tx = previous;
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();;
    var opts = $(this)[0].options;      
    var array = $.map(opts, function(elem) {
    return (elem.text || elem.text);
    });
    //alert(previoues_tx);
    //alert(selected);
    //alert(opts);
    //alert(array);
    $('.activ select').each(function() {
        var oki = $(this).text();
        if(previoues_tx != 'Choisir---------------' )
        //alert(oki);
        {
            $('select option[text="' + previoues_tx + '"]').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        }
    $('select option[text="' + selected + '"]').attr('selected','selected').attr('disabled', true);
    $('select option[text=""]').removeAttr('disabled'); 
  });
    previous = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    });
```

Comment: [is this what you're trying to do?](http://jsfiddle.net/8hzLo7n2/2/)

Comment: @billyonecan: your link should have been posted as an answer, and some explanations on what you did should have been welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the reference JsFiddle, similar option for all `select` box contain same value but in your case you kept as different.

I modified your example [see demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chandansharma/xL8p478y/5/) here